# Cannot switch activities in Android except one activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

So I have been making a simple four button app for my IT 1 class and have been having a problem with some code. I have four buttons that are supposed to call a startActivity and change to a different screen. The first button, labeled fire, works perfectly fine and works 100% of the time. The next button, labeled Earthquake doesn't work, even though the code is the same (without the parts that need to change). The other 2 buttons also do not work. I have tried making a new project, copying the working xml, copying the exact code. I cannot figure out why it doesn't work.

MainActivity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#81848b"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.carrieowen.testproject.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#eff2f9"
        android:text="Emergency Drills"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="40dp"
        android:text="Fire"
        android:background="#e71e1e"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="Fire"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#009c12"
        android:padding="40dp"
        android:text="Earthquake"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="Earthquake"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#eef035"
        android:padding="40dp"
        android:text="Tornado"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:onClick="Tornado"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#1b4fdd"
        android:padding="40dp"
        android:text="Code Blue"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:onClick="CodeBlue"/>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The MainActivity Java

```
package com.example.carrieowen.testproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    public void Fire (View view){
        Intent changeScreenFire = new Intent(this, firescreen.class);
        startActivity(changeScreenFire);
    }

    public void Earthquake (View view){
    Intent changeScreenEarthquake = new Intent(this, earthquake.class);
    startActivity(changeScreenEarthquake);
    }
    public void Tornado (View view){
        Intent changeScreenTornado = new Intent(this, tornado.class);
        startActivity(changeScreenTornado);
    }
    public void CodeBlue (View view){
        Intent changeScreenCodeBlue = new Intent(this, codeblue.class);
        startActivity(changeScreenCodeBlue);
    }

}
```

The FireScreen Java

```
package com.example.carrieowen.testproject;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class firescreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_firescreen);
    }
}
```

The Earthquake Java

```
package com.example.carrieowen.testproject;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class earthquake extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_earthquake);
    }
}
```

The XML for the Fire and Earthquake are the same other than the Text boxes being different. If needed will add.

Comment: What is happening when you click on the buttons? Do you get an exception?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.carrieowen.testproject, PID: 17111
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Comment: Did you add all of these activities in your Manifest file?

Comment: Just looked and nothing was there but the firescreen one. Im going to kill myself. I spent a week to find that out...

Comment: Always create your activities using the `New > Activity` step. Else you have to go and manually add them in your manifest

Comment: I did. I'm using git to VCS with 3 other people and i guess it didn't change it. I don't know but yea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your activities are listed in the manifest? The manifest file is called `AndroidManifest.xml` and is listed in the project at the top, in android studio. This is what the content should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Tornado">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CodeBlue">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I tried to add it as a comment, but it said I was too new and needed 50 reputation, or something like that. and I tried to delete it, but it won't let me. I'm new here, and still learning.

Comment: Okay. You can reword it to look like an answer since It solved the OP's problem

Comment: ok, I feel stupid. what does an answer look like? does it restate the question, or what?

Comment: No, it doesn't "restate" the question, It "answers" it. Preferably with code and/or image and most importantly, it should address the problem, providing a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like that as well, but my code is a bit different. Try it like this. The button that you used to create open the new activity is labeled in the line starting with Button Pause, then i set a onclicklistner so that when you click on it, something happens, and i have it to currently oped a new activity in the method past the @Override part.

```
public class GameWindow extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_window);

    Button pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pausebutton);
    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent(GameWindow.this, PauseMenu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code and how it can solve the problem